# How to make math font for LuaTeX with Fontforge?

Tags: fonts

I've read up on [Design With FontForge](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/index.html) and feel ready to make my first font except for the math-bit. Does anyone have a step-by-step manual for how to make math fonts usable in LuaTeX with Fontforge?

Comment: most of the freely accessible documents about the OTF math format are linked from here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math/index_html I think.

Comment: A similar question (but with a relatively unhelpful "Don't do it" answer) has some links in the comments that might be useful. [How would one design a math font?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/75022)  Also https://www.tug.org/twg/mfg/papers/jkuester/20040430-bachotex.pdf